# it is possible for the hydrogen bond to form between the hydrogen chloride molecule, HCl?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond, dipole

Recently I'm doing my work, and I can't find what it is the answer. Can you guys help me?

Comment: **HINT** What are the three most common states of matter?

Comment: Hydrogen bond is formed by three most electronegative elements: fluorine, oxygen, nitrogen.

Comment: @MaxW I believe he tries to find if the hydrogen bonds significantly affect the properties of the $\ce{HCl}$.

Comment: See  [Chloronium, H2Cl+, in Extragalactic Sources - cdms.astro.uni-koeln.de](https://cdms.astro.uni-koeln.de/classic/molecules:extragalactic:h2cl-plus_extragalactic).  But I suppose in water environment, it would be very unstable, with proton having  preference for oxygen.